# Print nested list in tabular form - Python (without Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, list, stdout, tabular

This is what I have:

```
list1 = [[7, 1, 0], [10, 2, 5], [6, 5, 9], [9, 9, 9], [1, 23, 12]]
```

I want to print it like this in the output WITHOUT using pandas library:

```
7 1 0
10 2 5
6 5 9
9 9 9
1 23 12
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple list comprehension and map can do the job:

```
list1 = [[7, 1, 0], [10, 2, 5], [6, 5, 9], [9, 9, 9], [1, 23, 12]]
print("\n".join([" ".join(map(str, i)) for i in list1]))
```